# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined 02

Tags: javascript

Es que estoy intentando abrir un calendario en JavaScript pero cuando le doy click me manda este error en el inspector del navegador. Este es el código HTML:

```
<input enabled="false" value="<%=request("fechainicial")%>" name="fechainicial" type="text" class="textbox" id="date1" size="10" maxlength="10" onFocus="this.blur(); showCal('Date1')"></td>
                          <td nowrap><div align="left"><a href="javascript:showCal('Date1')"><img src="../app/images/date.gif" width="17" height="17" border="0"></a></div>
```

Y este es el código de javascript:

```
function showCal(name) {
  var d=new Date();
  currentCal = findCalendar(name);
  if (currentCal != null) {
    var calRE = getFormat();
    if (currentCal.form[currentCal.field].value!="" && calRE.test(currentCal.form[currentCal.field].value)) {
      var cd = getDateNumbers(currentCal.form[currentCal.field].value);
      d=new Date(cd[0],cd[1],cd[2]);
      cY=cd[0];
      cM=cd[1];
      dd=cd[2];
    }
    else {
      cY=d.getFullYear();
      cM=d.getMonth();
      dd=d.getDate();
    }
    var calendar=calHeader()+calTitle(d)+calBody(d,dd)+calFooter();
    if (isIE) {
      layers[cal].style.pixelTop=getTopIE(layers[currentCal.id],true);
      layers[cal].style.pixelLeft=getLeftIE(layers[currentCal.id],true);
      layers[cal].innerHTML=calendar;
      layers[cal].style.clip = "rect(0px; " + layers[cal].children[0].offsetWidth + "px; " + layers[cal].children[0].offsetHeight + "px; 0px)";
    }
    else if (isN4) {
      layers[cal].top=getTopN4(layers[currentCal.id]);
      layers[cal].left=getLeftN4(layers[currentCal.id]);
      layers[cal].document.open();
      layers[cal].document.writeln(calendar);
      layers[cal].document.close();
      layers[cal].visibility="show";
    }
    else if (isN6) {
      var l=document.getElementById(currentCal.id);
      layer=document.getElementById(cal);
      layer.style.top=getTopN6(l)+"px";
      layer.style.left=getLeftN6(l)+"px";
      layer.innerHTML=calendar;
    }
  }
  else {
         if(typeof AlertClient=="function"){ AlertClient("Calendar.NotFound",name); }
         else { alert("Text not translated: \n" + "Calendar ["+name+"] not found"); }
  }
}
```

Mas que todo el error me lo vota en esta linea:

```
 if (currentCal.form[currentCal.field].value!="" && calRE.test(currentCal.form[currentCal.field].value)) {
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: ¿Ya habías preguntado esto hace unos minutos no? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279896/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined  de ser así te sugiero elimines una de las 2 y mejores la restante pues no es correcto duplicar preguntas.

Comment: Si, pero este esta con mas cosas y encima lo puse de nuevo, haber si alguien lo veía y lo respondía ya que el anterior nadie respondió, y necesitaba saber una posible solución por lo menos.

Comment: no recibirás la ayuda mas rápido por estar duplicando tus preguntas, además de que no es necesario pues si tenías contenido extra que añadir basta con que le des editar y agregues lo faltante, dicha acción generará que el sistema la coloque al inicio nuevamente, por favor quita una de las 2 y sigue las indicaciones que te doy

Comment: En ese caso me gustaría eliminar la primera que puse pero no se como hacerlo, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: justo debajo de la pregunta, existe un enlace que dice *eliminar* y así lo consigues

Comment: La variable currentCal.form[currentCal.field].value no existe por lo que no se puede leer una propiedad de una variable no definida, me explico mejor, la propiedad .value a la que intentas acceder no existe o no está declarada, te recomiendo que descompongas la variable en todas sus formas y te hagas unos cuantos console.log(currentCal); para ver exactamente que ocurre.